# Call to undefined function ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I can't seem to make zipArchive works. I asked my web host to enable ZLib and he told me he did. When I use phpinfo();

```
I get this:

Zlib Support: enabled

Stream Wrapper support: compress.zlib://

Stream Filter support: zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate

Compiled Version: 1.2.3

Linked Version: 1.2.3
```

I'm really lost here. I don't know what to do anymore.

EDIT: here's my simple code

```
$path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__); 
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($path);
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: it seems it's enabled as it shows up in phpinfo(); show us some code to see if you had one of those "forgot a bracket" mistakes or something xD

Comment: What did you try? What sense does such a question make without code??

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- `zip` and `zlib` are not the same;
- [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) is not a function, it is a class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate ZIP files, you need the [Zip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) extension, not [Zlib](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php).

Zip:

> enables you to transparently read or write **ZIP** compressed archives

Zlib:

> enables you to transparently read and write **gzip** (.gz) compressed files

Additionally, if you are getting the *Call to undefined function ZipArchive* error message, your code (which you don't show) can't be right, because [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) is a **class**, not a function.